# How to deploy a full (web) application using Docker, if each process must be a container?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand how Docker is supposed to be used.

It's not clear whether I should put *everything* I need in a single Dockerfile. I've read some people saying that the current best practice is to have one container per process, eg: web server, database, and language interpreter would make 3 containers.

But how do I pack all those containers together? Does that responsibility belong to Docker, or do I have to use something else? To get started I could write a simple bash script that installs all the containers I need. Is that the way to go?

Another question (maybe I should open a separate thread for this): What's the most common practice? To use the default server for "docker push", or to host your own?

Answer (score 1):

First your second question. A good reason to use a private  repository is if your images are, well... private. The most common practice I guess is that people that do not have a private  repository use the public index, simply because it's easy. If you want to open source something, surely use the public index. But if you have a private project that would be the time to start a private index.

Concerning your first question. I think you're heading the right way. Yes, it is logical to use Docker to establish a separation of concerns by setting up a container for as many of the UML blocks in your setup as possible. Since docker is so efficient this is possible. This makes sure that you can deploy your containers on different hosts later, even though you might not need that initially.
Indeed, the communication between those containers is not the responsibility of docker, although it provides linking for instance (but linking is not much more than setting a couple of environment variables, which you can do in other ways as well).
Me: I go for the bash script approach that you mention. packing containers together is not dockers responsibility.

Good luck.